# Unable to get total amount

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi guys I have fixed the initial problem but now its not adding up correctly. I am unsure what to do and where I have gone wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class zoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
  int quantity, confirm, option, finalTotal;
  float childTotal = 0;
  float adultTotal = 0;
  float seniorTotal = 0;

  final double childCost = 18;
  final double adultCost = 36;
  final double seniorCost = 32.50;

  int Option[] = new int[3];
  Option[0] = 1;
  Option[1] = 2;
  Option[2] = 3;

  boolean  continueLoop = true; 
  char resume;

    switch (option) {

            case 1:
                childTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*childCost) ;
                System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
                break;

            case 2:
                adultTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*adultCost) ;
                System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
                break;

            default:
                seniorTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*seniorCost);
                System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
                break;
              }

    System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
    resume = input.next().charAt(0);

       switch (option) {
            case 1:
            finalTotal=(int) ((double) childCost+childTotal);
            System.out.println("Total amount for tickets: $" + finalTotal);
            break;
        case 2:
            finalTotal=(int) ((double) adultCost+adultTotal) ;
            System.out.println("Total amount for tickets $" + finalTotal);
            break;
        default:
            finalTotal=(int) ((double) seniorCost+seniorTotal);
            System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + finalTotal);
            break;
          }
```

Comment: Could you actually point to the location the variables are initialized? You included source code, but it seems the source of the problem is missing.

Comment: @Glains i have fixed the initial problem but now its not adding up correctly

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @Mureinik at the end of the program it should calculate the total amount which has been chosen. the program is designed to re run the program if the user would like to choose more tickets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get total amount payable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536966/unable-to-get-total-amount-payable)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed issues and also updated code for better performance.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSE1PGX_A2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final float childCost = 18;
        final float adultCost = 36;
        final float seniorCost = 32.50F;

        boolean continueLoop = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            float childTotal = 0;
            float adultTotal = 0;
            float seniorTotal = 0;

        while (continueLoop) {
            int option, confirm=0;

            System.out.println("\t @@@@@ Welcome to Zoos Victoria @@@@@");
            System.out.println("\t \t MAIN MENU \n");
            System.out.println("\t Zoo has the following ticketing options \n");
            System.out.println("\t 1 = Child (4-6 yrs)");
            System.out.println("\t 2 = Adult (16+ yrs)");
            System.out.println("\t 3 = Senior (60+ yrs) \n");
            System.out.println("Enter your option:");

            option = input.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Child:");
                    int quantity = input.nextInt();
                    childTotal = quantity * childCost;

                    System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " child tickets at " + childCost + " each!");
                    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                    confirm = input.nextInt();
                    if (confirm == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Adult:");
                    int quantity = input.nextInt();
                    adultTotal = quantity * adultCost ;

                    System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " adult tickets at " + adultCost + " each!");

                    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                    confirm = input.nextInt();
                    if (confirm == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Senior:");
                    int quantity = input.nextInt();
                    seniorTotal =  quantity * seniorCost ;
                    System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " senior tickets at " + seniorCost + " each!");

                    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                    confirm = input.nextInt();
                    if (confirm == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (confirm != 1) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect key!");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
            char resume = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (resume != 'y' && resume != 'Y') {
            continueLoop = false;

            System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
            System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
            System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
            float  finalTotal =  childTotal + adultTotal + seniorTotal ;
            System.out.println("Total amount payable: $ " + finalTotal);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you trying to do something like this:

```
public int someMethod(){
    int childTotal; // here variable must be initialized before return
                    // like this int childTotal = 0;
        switch (option) {
            case 1:
            childTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*childCost) ;
            System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
            break;
        }
        ...
        return childTotal;
}
```

in this case you'll get an error, that variable must be initialized.

Anyway you gave to few information about your problem. Maybe you can show what kind of answer you get from the system, stackTrace or something like that. 
Did you know about diference between initialize and declare?