# Unable to get total amount payable

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: problem]

I have designed a program which will rerun when the user enters "y" when asked if they wish to continue. The problem I am having is once the user enters "n" the program is supposed to display the total amount payable from all ticket options purchased. I have spent a couple of weeks stuck on this problem and am unsure of what to do next. I have only included the bottom part of my code. I have also included a photo to show my problem when the program is run.

here is my code:

```
package cse1pgx_a2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CSE1PGX_A2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int option, quantity, confirm;
      float childTotal = 0;
      float adultTotal = 0;
      float seniorTotal = 0;
      float finalTotal = 0;

      final double childCost = 18;
      final double adultCost = 36;
      final double seniorCost = 32.50;

      boolean  continueLoop = true; 
      char resume;


      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      while (continueLoop)  {

        System.out.println("\t"+  "@@@@@ Welcome to Zoos Victoria @@@@@");
        System.out.println("\t" + "\t" + "MAIN MENU" + "\n");
        System.out.println("\t" + "Zoo has the following ticketing options" + "\n");
        System.out.println("\t" + "1 = Child (4-6 yrs)");
        System.out.println("\t" + "2 = Adult (16+ yrs)");
        System.out.println("\t" + "3 = Senior (60+ yrs)" + "\n");

        System.out.println("Enter your option:" );
        option=input.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Child:" );
                quantity=input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " child tickets at " + childCost + " each!");

                System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                confirm=input.nextInt();

                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Adult:" );
                quantity=input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " adult tickets at " + adultCost + " each!");

                System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                confirm=input.nextInt();

                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Senior:" );
                quantity=input.nextInt();

                System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " senior tickets at " + seniorCost + " each!");

                System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                confirm=input.nextInt();

                break;
        }

        if (confirm !=1) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect key!");
        }

        OUTER:
        while (confirm == 1) {
            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    childTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*childCost) ;
                    System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
                    break OUTER;
                case 2:
                    adultTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*adultCost) ;
                    System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
                    break OUTER;
                default:
                    seniorTotal=(int) ((double) quantity*seniorCost);
                    System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
                    break OUTER;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
        resume = input.next().charAt(0);

       if (resume == 'y' || resume == 'Y') {
              } else {

                  continueLoop = false;

                  switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        finalTotal=(float) ((double) childTotal+adultTotal+seniorTotal) ;
                        System.out.println("Total amount payable: $ " + finalTotal);
                        break;

                    default: 
                        System.out.println("Error");

                  }
       }
}
    }
}
```

Comment: when are you printing the "finalTotal" variable?

Comment: You are not clear. Refer this place to learn how to ask questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Bec i assume u have skipped code in if condition and look to shorten the question. I would like to suggest some code improvement. can u please add the code in if (resume == 'y' || resume == 'Y') { ....   }

Comment: @Rupesh yes it wouldnt allow me to add all code, i have fixed the question and added more explanation

Comment: @Bec I have fixed issues and also updated code for better performance. Please take a look and accept and vote the answer if it solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed issues and also updated code for better performance.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSE1PGX_A2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final float childCost = 18;
        final float adultCost = 36;
        final float seniorCost = 32.50F;

        boolean continueLoop = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            float childTotal = 0;
            float adultTotal = 0;
            float seniorTotal = 0;

        while (continueLoop) {
            int option, confirm=0;

            System.out.println("\t @@@@@ Welcome to Zoos Victoria @@@@@");
            System.out.println("\t \t MAIN MENU \n");
            System.out.println("\t Zoo has the following ticketing options \n");
            System.out.println("\t 1 = Child (4-6 yrs)");
            System.out.println("\t 2 = Adult (16+ yrs)");
            System.out.println("\t 3 = Senior (60+ yrs) \n");
            System.out.println("Enter your option:");

            option = input.nextInt();

            switch (option) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Child:");
                    int quantity = input.nextInt();
                    childTotal = quantity * childCost;

                    System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " child tickets at " + childCost + " each!");
                    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                    confirm = input.nextInt();
                    if (confirm == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Adult:");
                    int quantity = input.nextInt();
                    adultTotal = quantity * adultCost ;

                    System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " adult tickets at " + adultCost + " each!");

                    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                    confirm = input.nextInt();
                    if (confirm == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("Enter total No of tickets for Senior:");
                    int quantity = input.nextInt();
                    seniorTotal =  quantity * seniorCost ;
                    System.out.println("You are purchasing " + quantity + " senior tickets at " + seniorCost + " each!");

                    System.out.println("Press 1 to confirm");
                    confirm = input.nextInt();
                    if (confirm == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (confirm != 1) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect key!");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
            char resume = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (resume != 'y' && resume != 'Y') {
            continueLoop = false;

            System.out.println("Total amount for child tickets: $" + childTotal);
            System.out.println("Total amount for senior tickets $" + seniorTotal);
            System.out.println("Total amount for adult tickets $" + adultTotal);
            float  finalTotal =  childTotal + adultTotal + seniorTotal ;
            System.out.println("Total amount payable: $ " + finalTotal);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I implented what you have suggested but the program no longer re runs run:
 @@@@@ Welcome to Zoos Victoria @@@@@
  MAIN MENU

 Zoo has the following ticketing options

 1 = Child (4-6 yrs)
 2 = Adult (16+ yrs)
 3 = Senior (60+ yrs)

Enter your option:
1
Enter total No of tickets for Child:
1
You are purchasing 1 child tickets at 18.0 each!
Press 1 to confirm
1
Total amount for child tickets: $18.0
Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) 
y
Total amount payable: $ 18.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)

Comment: I have fixed the problem sorry but thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I hope it helps.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          int option, quantity, confirm;       //minor change

          float childTotal = 0;
          float adultTotal = 0;
          float seniorTotal = 0;
          float finalTotal = 0;            //minor change

          final double childCost = 18;
          final double adultCost = 36;
          final double seniorCost = 32.50;

          boolean  continueLoop = true; 
          char resume;
          System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N) ");
          resume = input.next().charAt(0);

           if (resume == 'y' || resume == 'Y') {
                  }else{
                      continueLoop = false;
                      switch (option) {
                        case 1:
                            finalTotal+=(double) quantity*childTotal ; //minor change
                            System.out.println("Total amount payable: $" + childTotal);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            finalTotal+=(double)  quantity*adultTotal ; //minor change
                            System.out.println("Total amount payable $" + adultTotal);
                            break;
                        default:
                            finalTotal+=(double) quantity*seniorTotal; //minor change
                            System.out.println("Total amount payable $" + seniorTotal);
                            break;
                      }
           }
    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wished to play and did not fully understand the problem...so i developed from scratch the application. Suryakant was faster so please accept his answer (if it solves your problem). I simply post this here since i worked on it :-)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean continueLoop = true;
        Map<TicketType, Integer> purchases=new HashMap<>();
        do {
            TicketType type = printMenu(scan);
            System.out.println("Enter number of tickets for " + type.label);
            int quantity = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You are purchasing "+quantity + " "+ type.label+ " ticket at "+type.cost+" each. " +
                    "Press 1 to confirm?");
            int confirm= scan.nextInt();
            if (confirm!=1) continue;
            if (purchases.containsKey(type)){
                purchases.put(type,purchases.get(type)+quantity);
                System.out.println("You now have " +purchases.get(type) +" "+type.label +" tickets in total");
            }else {
                purchases.put(type,quantity);
            }
            System.out.println("You have added " +quantity +" "+type.label +" tickets in your basket.");
            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue (Y|N)?");
            String resume=scan.next();
            if (resume.startsWith("Y") || resume.startsWith("y")){
                continueLoop=true;
            }else {
                continueLoop=false;
            }
        }while (continueLoop);

        System.out.println("Purchases");
        long total=0;
        for (Map.Entry<TicketType, Integer> ticketTypeIntegerEntry : purchases.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(ticketTypeIntegerEntry.getKey().label+"("+ticketTypeIntegerEntry.getValue()+")");
            total+=ticketTypeIntegerEntry.getKey().cost*ticketTypeIntegerEntry.getValue();
        }

        System.out.println("Total payable ammount: "+total);

    }

    private static TicketType printMenu(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        TicketType type;
        int k = -1;
        do {
            for (TicketType ticketType : TicketType.values()) {
                System.out.println(ticketType.id + ". for " + ticketType.label);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter your option");
            k = scan.nextInt();
        } while ((type=TicketType.valuefromId(k))==null);
        return type;
    }

    private enum TicketType {
        CHILD(1, "Child", 18D),
        ADULT(2, "Adult", 36D),
        SENIOR(3, "Senior", 18.5D);
        int id;
        String label;
        double cost;

        private static Map<Integer,TicketType> map=new HashMap<Integer,TicketType>();
        static {
            for (TicketType ticketType : TicketType.values()) {
                map.put(ticketType.id,ticketType);
            }
        }
        TicketType(int id, String label, double cost) {
            this.id = id;
            this.label = label;
            this.cost=cost;
        }

        public static TicketType valuefromId(int id){
                return map.get(id);
        }
    }
}
```

improvements are in reading.. i would check first if what i read is character or not..